# Android NDK: ERROR:jni/Android.mk:cocos_jpeg_static: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x-2.x

Here is my Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := cocos_jpeg_static
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := jpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libjpeg.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes                   

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static cocos_extension_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) \
$(call import-module,cocos2dx) \
$(call import-module,extensions)
```

When I run ./build_native.sh command in my terminal after providing the path of my Android Ndk I got the following errors :-

```
Android NDK: ERROR:jni/Android.mk:cocos_jpeg_static: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
Android NDK: Check that jni/libs/armeabi-v7a/libjpeg.a exists  or that its path is correct
```

I am not pro at programming so would like to get some advise on it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that jni/libs/armeabi-v7a/libjpeg.a exists  or that its path is correct?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your comment , and yes i do had checked the path and had found the .a file ,Here is my full path (/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/libs/armeabi-v7a/libpng.a)

Comment: So now you have to put it inside your **jni** folder

Comment: jni folder of my project ?? , Which i have created ??

Comment: Hey , I have just put the libs folder in my jni folder. and then i run the command again (./build_native.sh) and got this response :-

Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'cocos_jpeg_static' in /home/ravi/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030_Full_ADT_Working_tool/cocos2d-x-cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2/TestMe/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libjpeg/Android.mk.    
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by jni/Android.mk.

Comment: So you put the entire content of /cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng/libs folder inside the jni's project folder? And it still doesn't compile?

Comment: I have copied whole content i.e everything which i was having in prebuilt folder (all the lib Folders) in my jni folder of project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67618/discussion-between-albemala-and-sid).

Comment: It reports that libjpeg.a is missing, have you checked that file instead of libpng.a